# What punctuation is right for the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

What should I put after "let's face it"?

> Let’s face it; in one way or another, we work out because we want to
>   improve and become stronger. How we do this, however, defines the
>   amount of improvement

Comment: A semicolon works fine, and so does a dash or a period. Commas are right out; this is a full stop intonation.

Comment: I like dashes better, so thanks for clarifying everything, mate!

Answer (score 2):

To me, a colon makes the most sense.  You are stating what you meant by 'it'.  When you restate the meaning of what you just said in a clearer way, or resolve a forward pronoun reference, you use a colon.

It is parallel to situations where you use 'Do the following:', or 'I have these concerns:', and put the list after the colon.  Only in this case, there is only one item being 'forward referenced'.